# Make a method both static and instance

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called `Foo` and a static method - `Bar (Foo instance)` - inside it. But instead of only being able to call it like `Foo.Bar(new Foo())`, I want to also be able to say `new Foo().Bar();`

TL;DR I have a static method in class `Foo` which has a parameter of type `Foo` and I want to also be able to call it as if it was a non-static method.

<sup>This is all for testing purposes. I know this'd be terrible code design.</sup>

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Make an extension method.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk: an extension method will not support calling via `Foo.Bar(new Foo());`

Comment: To the OP: it is not clear at all what you hope to achieve with this. You almost certainly have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you are going to have to have an _instance_ of `Foo` whether you call a static method or a non-static method, _what could possibly be the point of having the static method_?

Comment: `void Bar() => Bar(this);` - but i think doing what you want to do is quite a weird design choice. not bad, but... _weird_

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, he already has method static void Bar (Foo instance) which supports calling via Foo.Bar(new Foo());
To be able to call Foo.Bar(new Foo()); he can add an extension method.

Comment: Yes possible. Because signatures are different.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk But to be able to call this extension method as `Foo.Bar(new Foo())`;  it would have to be a member of the `Foo` class. But that isn't possible, because extension methods can only be members of `static` classes, but `Foo` can't be a static class, because it will have non-static members ...

Comment: @derpirscher that's why he needs his already existing method and a new one, possibly extension method, to be able to call the method from an instance of an object. I don't see anywhere in the question that he wants 1 method to behave like both, static and instance.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk If there is already a static `public static void Bar(Foo instance)` method , wouldn't it be way easier to just add a non-static `public void Bar()` method to the `Foo` class? This will allow to call `Foo.Bar(new Foo())` and `new Foo().Bar()` just as OP requested (if that really makes sense or not is a totally different question). For your suggestion of an extension method, you need an additional static class, which in this scenario doesn't have any benefit at all, but just adds additional complexity ....

Comment: @derpirscher well, yeah, I agree with you. I just supposed that he don't have source code for some class with a static method, so he cannot redesign a class, but want to call the method from the instance of an object. In my mind, it is the only one reason to ask his question. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create both methods, and let one redirect to other, where main logic is:

```
public class Foo
{
    // Called by Foo.Bar(new Foo());
    public static void Bar(Foo instance)
    {
        // logic here
    }

    // Called by new Foo().Bar();
    public void Bar()
    {
       Foo.Bar(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could add a note to the answer telling that what OP wants does not make much sense.

Comment: @Cleptus This really is strange design, but OP hasn't provided any context for me to tell him that this doesn't make sense. He is just asking for specific language feature.

Comment: IMHO it is not strange design but [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Well, I also think it might be bad design, but I was still curious.

Comment: Your logic will always work on Foo instance. Is there a reason you want static method, or you are just testing C# syntax and stuff (for learning purposes)?

Comment: @Mitko Just testing syntax.